# Mouseover and Mouseout not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseout

Trying to use these jQuery methods to show a description on hover of the image it describes.... It will sort of work if I dont set description display to none, in which case the doc starts with all descriptions showing, but then will show and hide them (all of them) as I mouseover and mouseout. But I want the descriptions to be hidden until the first mouseover. I'm also having an issue matching the image/description hovers to each instance. I am new at OOP, but I think that would come in handy here. Anyway, any tips are appreciated!

Here's my code:

```js
    $('.image').mouseover(function() {
      $('.description').show();
    })
    
    $('.image').mouseout(function() {
      $('.description').hide();
    })
```

```css
    .col-lg-3 h2 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Arial';
      margin-left: .1em;
      font-weight: 500;
      display: none;
    
    }
    
    .col-lg-3 p {
      font-size: .9em;
      margin-left: .2em;
      margin-top: -.3em;
      font-weight: 400;
      display: none;
```

```html
      <div class="col-lg-3 project1">
        <a class = "image" href="" target="_blank"> <img width="100%" height="100%" src="" alt=""></a> 
        <div class = "description">
          <h2>  </h2> 
          <p>  </p>
        </div>
```

If I want this to only work on the instances of image/description pairs, I should probably add some .this stuff too, no?

Comment: can you put it into jsfiddle and share it ?

Comment: `I am new at OOP` where is OOP ? and you have not used javascript at all here , its jQuery only.

Comment: Yup, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/6x8bmatx/1/

Comment: And yes there is no OOP here. What I'm saying is that I probably should have built the elements with JS and then added them to my html... given that i have multiple instances of an object. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Do u want to show description on DOM Ready ?

Comment: @user3757351 checkout possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/6x8bmatx/2/

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura Sweet. Halfway solved. Still need to figure out how I should use .this in order to make the only the right description show at one time. For now, it displays all descriptions whenever I hover over any image.

Comment: @user3757351 understand your concern now completely checkout this now http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/6x8bmatx/4/

Comment: @coolalligator15 Let me add to answer so other will get solution

Answer (score -1):

checkout below solution

**JS PART**: change jQuery selector

```
$('.image').mouseover(function() {
  $('.description *', $(this).parent()).show();
})

$('.image').mouseout(function() {
  $('.description *', $(this).parent()).hide();
})
```

**CSS PART**: no change

```
.col-lg-3 h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  margin-left: .1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;

}

.col-lg-3 p {
  font-size: .9em;
  margin-left: .2em;
  margin-top: -.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML PART**: add proper ending `</div>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 ye">
            <a class = "image" href="targethere" target="_blank"> <img width="10%" height="10%" src="http://srdtu.org/assets/img/events/quiz-.jpg.jpg" alt="quiz"></a> 
            <div class = "description">
            <h2> quiz </h2> 
            <p> a quote guessing game </p>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please read OP's question `I dont set description display to none, `

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yes i have remove that css part

Answer (score -1):

Don't use mouseout and mouseover. There are lots of things which you've to consider when you are using these functions.. I will suggest you to use hover function..

```
$('.image').hover(function() { $('.description').show(); }, function() { $('.description').hide(); });
```

1st parameter is the function which executes on mouseover and 2nd function executes at mouse out.

Comment: it's working fine but issue was with your css. i've fixed.. please check [https://jsfiddle.net/6x8bmatx/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/6x8bmatx/5/)